unable to show App Open ads in .NEt MAUI APP (.NET 9)
Below code i am using to integrate the admob to show the open App ad. but is does not show any add.. OnAdLoaded and OnAdFailedToLoad function never called . Pls let me know where i am wrong.
Pls share if you have any other way to implement the same. is there any nuget provided by Microsoft for this?
MainActivity calling  function
// this is called in MainActivity android file
    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();
        var adManager = new AppOpenAdManager(this);
        adManager.LoadAd("addunit");
        adManager.ShowAdIfAvailable(this);
    }

AppOpenAdManager.cs


public class AppOpenAdManager
{
    private AppOpenAd appOpenAd;
    private bool isAdShowing = false;
    private Context context;

    public AppOpenAdManager(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void LoadAd(string adUnitId)
    {
        AppOpenAd.Load(
       context,
       adUnitId,
       new AdRequest.Builder().Build(),
       new AppOpenAdLoadCallbackHandler(
           ad => { appOpenAd = ad; },
           error => { /* Handle ad load failure */ }
       ));
       
    }

    public void ShowAdIfAvailable(Activity activity)
    {
        if (appOpenAd != null && !isAdShowing)
        {
            appOpenAd.FullScreenContentCallback = new CustomFullScreenContentCallback(
                () =>
                {
                    isAdShowing = false;
                    appOpenAd = null;
                },
                () =>
                {
                    isAdShowing = true;
                }
            );

            appOpenAd.Show(activity);
        }
    }
}
public class AppOpenAdLoadCallbackHandler : AppOpenLoadCallback
{
    private readonly Action<AppOpenAd> onAdLoaded;
    private readonly Action<LoadAdError> onAdFailedToLoad;

    public AppOpenAdLoadCallbackHandler(Action<AppOpenAd> onAdLoaded, Action<LoadAdError> onAdFailedToLoad)
    {
        this.onAdLoaded = onAdLoaded;
        this.onAdFailedToLoad = onAdFailedToLoad;
    }

    public override void OnAdLoaded(AppOpenAd ad)
    {
        onAdLoaded?.Invoke(ad);
    }

    public override void OnAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError error)
    {
        onAdFailedToLoad?.Invoke(error);
    }
}
public class CustomFullScreenContentCallback : FullScreenContentCallback
{
    private readonly Action onAdDismissed;
    private readonly Action onAdShowedFullScreenContent;

    public CustomFullScreenContentCallback(Action onAdDismissed, Action onAdShowedFullScreenContent)
    {
        this.onAdDismissed = onAdDismissed;
        this.onAdShowedFullScreenContent = onAdShowedFullScreenContent;
    }

    public override void OnAdDismissedFullScreenContent()
    {
        onAdDismissed?.Invoke();
    }

    public override void OnAdShowedFullScreenContent()
    {
        onAdShowedFullScreenContent?.Invoke();
    }
}
   

public abstract class AppOpenLoadCallback : AppOpenAdLoadCallback
{
    [Register("onAdLoaded", "(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/appopen/AppOpenAd;)V", "GetOnAdLoadedHandler")]
    public virtual void OnAdLoaded(AppOpenAd appOpenAd)
    {
    }

    private static Delegate cb_onAdLoaded;
    private static Delegate GetOnAdLoadedHandler()
    {
        if (cb_onAdLoaded is null)
            cb_onAdLoaded = JNINativeWrapper.CreateDelegate((Action<IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr>)n_onAdLoaded);
        return cb_onAdLoaded;
    }
    private static void n_onAdLoaded(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_p0)
    {
        AppOpenAdLoadCallback thisobject = GetObject<AppOpenAdLoadCallback>(jnienv, native__this, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer);
        AppOpenAd resultobject = GetObject<AppOpenAd>(native_p0, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer);
        thisobject.OnAdLoaded(resultobject);
    }
}

